# PHP CSV: Echo 2 subarray values dependent on third subarray

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I need to create an HTML table for a schedule, but I do not need to utilize all of the information.

```
The output I want is

Category 1 - Room
Time-Time - Company 4
Time-Time - Company 2
Time-Time - Company 21

Category 2 - Room
Time-Time - Company 8
Time-Time - Company 13
Time-Time - Company 7

IE:

CNS/Neurology – Wellesley
9:15 am – Company 4
9:30 am – Company 2
9:45 am – Company 21

Drug Discovery – Suffolk
9:45 am – Company 8
10:00 am – Company 13
10:15 am – Company 7
```

They are printed alphabetically by Category, then chronological time, and need to check that there is a value of 'x' in another column (array post_to_web).

Currently I have the category and the company in a combined subarray printing seperately, but I need to combine them based on the X in another column and use the other data in that specific row. I also need to strip extra spaces in front and behind the value of the category and company

CSV Headers:
Comments | Status | Company | Regtype | Category | Round/Date invited | confirmed invite | PRS SPEC. REQUEST | PRS day | PRS date | PRS time | PRS level | PRS room | Post to Web

accepted 7/18 | blank | 490 BioTech | NXT | Next Generation | blank | blank | blank | Wednesday | 24-Sep | 10:30 AM | Level 3 | Suffolk | X

Full code:

```
<?php

$filename = "testing.csv";

$companies = array();
$category = array();
$prs_day = array();
$prs_date = array();
$prs_time = array();
$prs_level = array();
$prs_room = array();
$post_to_web = array();

if (($file = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($arr = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

        $companies[] = $arr[2];
        $category[] = $arr[4];
        $prs_day[] = $arr[8];
        $prs_date[] = $arr[9];
        $prs_time[] = $arr[10];
        $prs_level[] = $arr[11];
        $prs_room[] = $arr[12];
        $post_to_web[] = $arr[13];

}

fclose($file);  
}

//create subarray
$category_companies_combined = array($category, $companies);

echo "<br />";

//create subarray[0]
$input_categories = $category_companies_combined[0];
$result_categories = array_unique($input_categories);

// Sort the multidimensional array
     usort($result_categories, "custom_sort");
     // Define the custom sort function
     function custom_sort($a,$b) {
          return $a['some_sub_var']>$b['some_sub_var'];
     }

//echo the results
echo "<table width=\"600px\">";
foreach($result_categories as $value){ 
    echo "<tr><td>".$value."</td></tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";

echo "<br />";

//create subarray[1]
$input_companies = $category_companies_combined[1];
$result_companies = array_unique($input_companies);

//echo the results
echo "<table width=\"600px\">";
foreach($result_companies as $value){ 
    echo "<tr><td>".$value."</td></tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Currently this echos all categories properly in alpha order, but I need to put the appropriate companies into each category with their chronological time based on post_to_web value of 'x'.

```
Current output:

Autoimmune/Inflammation
Academic Innovatorsâ„¢ Showcase
Antibodies
Biomarkers/Diagnostics/Imaging
Category
CNS/Neurology
Cancer
Drug Discovery
Gene therapy
Infectious Disease
Metabolism
Next Generation
Pharma and Large Biotech
Portuguese Delegation
Respiratory
Specialty Pharma

Company 1
Company 2
Company 3
Company 4
Company 5
Company 6
... etc
```

Comment: show your csv file format too.

Comment: thanks, headers and example row have been added

Comment: will you be able to join the day, date, month year and time in single cell? Otherwise you need to concatenate. Please let me know.

Comment: unfortunately no, they need to be combined in the code

Comment: X mark decides the data need to be included in table?

Comment: Not so easy, as your time is separated, and it is required to be combined, data need to be reformatted, and moreover, sorting is to be done. This forum will help if you are stuck at some place, we won't provide you complete code free.

Comment: Aye, I would say the date could be left alone if the day was used as the key. If I had to I suppose I could sort the csv by day/time so there was less work in the code